# ImportError: No module named 'xlsxwriter'

Tags: python, pip, virtual-machine

I have a Flask server.
I was working locally and it was working.
I uploaded the server on a VM (Debian) of my university and it gives me an error.
If I try to run it in python 2, it gives me this error:

```
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/firebase/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
from urllib.parse import urlencode, quote
ImportError: No module named parse
```

I also tried to import urlparse for python2:

```
try:
   from urllib.parse import urlparse
except ImportError:
    from urlparse import urlparse
```

but it still gives me the same error.

If I try to run it in python3, it gives me this error:

```
 File "flask_server.py", line 8, in <module>
import xlsxwriter
ImportError: No module named 'xlsxwriter'
```

I tried to install it again via pip but it says:

```
Requirement already satisfied: xlsxwriter in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (1.3.7)
```

Should I ask to VM admin to change something in the env?

Help me,please.

Comment: `urllib` is an outdated module, instead people use the `requests` module.

Comment: You say that you are trying to run the program with python3 but pip shows that xlsxwriter is installed for python2. You probably need to install it with pip3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is going wrong here is that your `xlsxwriter` is in a seperate Python directory. You should probably go to that file path (where it says xlsx is), delete the file, and reinstall it via pip, or specify pip3.